# How can I find the range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the equation $f(x)=-x^2 +2x -7$, I am told the range is $(-\infty,-6]$. I feel the domain should be $(-\infty, \infty)$ because we can put any value in for $x$ and still get a real number. If the domain is $(-\infty,\infty)$, what makes the range $(-\infty, -6]$? I don't get it. Is there a more intuitive way for me to understand this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a graph of $f$?

Comment: Can you recite your definition of range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range is the set of values the function can take.  You are correct the domain is all of $\mathbb R$.  If you plot this, it is a parabola opening downward and $-6$ is the vertex.  You can see this by writing $f(x)=-(x-1)^2-6.$  The squared term has a maximum value of $0$, so the the maximum of $f(x)$ is $-6$.

Comment: That helped tremendously.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about the domain. The range is simply all the possible values that $f(x)$ can take. If you graph $y=f(x)$ you will see that it is an "upside-down" parabola. Therefore it has a maximum $y$ value which happens to be -6.